# How to construct orthogonal basis from a missing vectors?

Tags: matrices

I have $m$ vectors with a missing element each.

$v_i=(*, a_{2i},\cdots,a_{ni})^\mathrm{T}\,\forall\, i\in\{1, \cdots, m\}.$

I would like to add the missing element $*$ to all $v_i$'s such that all $v_i$ form an orthogonal basis. Is that possible? What are the conditions on the given $v_i$'s so the construction is possible?

For example: I have $\begin{pmatrix}*&*&*\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\\\end{pmatrix}$

So I can get:$\begin{pmatrix}\color{red}{0}&\color{red}{0}&\color{red}{1}\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\\\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: You can always do Gram-Schmidt to complete a basis. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

Answer (score 0):

If you have an orthonormal basis, the matrix $M$ with the columns as the orthonormal basis vectors will be an orthogonal matrix, i.e. $M^T M =I$. Therefore $M^T$ will also be an orthogonal matrix. Hence we can view the columns of $M^T$ (or the rows of $M$) as an orthonormal basis. So, in your case, by looking at the rows, you have $n-1$ orthonormal vectors and are seeking the last basis vector. This can be found by then taking a vector in the orthogonal complement and normalizing.

Comment: I guess that the author's problem is exactly the last sentence of your answer.